# How to draw a 'proportion graph' in Julia?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image: example proportion plot]

I've looked at all of the examples in the documentation and could not find a similar graph.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-plot-a-simple-stacked-area-chart/21351/2 try this

Comment: A stacked area chart is pretty close to what I am looking for, with the only real difference being the axis labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @sanidhya-singh's link also gives a built-in solution:

```
julia> areaplot(1:3, [1 2 3; 7 8 9; 4 5 6], seriescolor = [:red :green :blue], fillalpha = [0.2 0.3 0.4])
```

which gives

[image]

Maybe worth adding to the docs though!

---

[**EDIT**] This example has been added to the [Plots.jl docs](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/gallery/gr/generated/gr-ref58/#gr_demo_58)

Comment: @Krish, FYI, this example has just been added to the gallery: https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/gallery/gr/generated/gr-ref58/#gr_demo_58

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way:

```
using Plots

@userplot StackedArea

# a simple "recipe" for Plots.jl to get stacked area plots
# usage: stackedarea(xvector, datamatrix, plotsoptions)
@recipe function f(pc::StackedArea)
    x, y = pc.args
    n = length(x)
    y = cumsum(y, dims=2)
    seriestype := :shape

    # create a filled polygon for each item
    for c=1:size(y,2)
        sx = vcat(x, reverse(x))
        sy = vcat(y[:,c], c==1 ? zeros(n) : reverse(y[:,c-1]))
        @series (sx, sy)
    end
end

a = [1,1,1,1.5,2,3]
b = [0.5,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.2]
c = [2,1.8,2.2,3.3,2.5,1.8]
sNames = ["a","b","c"]
```

[image]

source: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-plot-a-simple-stacked-area-chart/21351/2